# Rails : Heroku CI : Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) for test env

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cleardb, heroku-ci

I have deployed a rails app to heroku, using mysql database hosted on a remote server. For this I have added the heroku addon 'cleardb' and setup correct ENV Config vars specifying:

```
DATABASE_URL = mysql2://user:password@host?reconnect=true
```

I have also setup Heroku continuous deployment for three branches, (branch -> environment)

```
develop -> devint,
staging -> staging,
master -> production
```

Continuous deployment works fine, and the database is setup fine too (because when I create a record in rails app, I can see the data in remote mysql host).

My issue is that when I enable HEROKU CI, the build fails every time with an error saying `Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`

Full error here: https://gist.github.com/siddhantbhardwaj/dab7c435815e7729d0f70081449f21ff#file-gistfile1-txt

This occurs when Heroku CI tries to perform `rake db:schema:load_if_ruby` for the :test env

My database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: what_course_development
  username: user
  password: password
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  <<: *default
  database: what_course_test

devint:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

staging:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please review below suggestion for configure your database.yml from DATABASE_URL:

```
DatabaseUrl.to_active_record_hash('postgres://uuu:xxx@127.0.0.1:1234/abc')
```

This will provide the below result:

```
{:adapter=>"postgres", :host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>1234, :database=>"abc", :user=>"uuu", :password=>"xxx"}
```

Please refer [seamusabshere database_url](https://github.com/seamusabshere/database_url) for more information.

Comment: Hi Darpan, do you want me to use the above command to convert DATABASE_URL into ruby hash and use that in database.yml?
If so, I think heroku config of DATABASE_URL is working fine, it is just that the Heroku CI build fails when it tries to prepare database for test env.

Comment: Yes i was suggested you the same and as per your comment i think you have fixed the issue, Thanks Siddhant.

Comment: No, the database was already working fine and records are saved in the database, but Heroku CI build fails with the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Siddhant did you ever figure this out? I am running into a similar issue

My thought is that the 127... in your error gist means that it is trying to connect to a local mysql instance inside the heroku-ci dyno. This won't work. 
I am thinking I instead need to set up a remote database for the test environment but am getting errors as I initially try to connect to a custom Amazon RDS DB